# How do I start a Django project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm attempting to use Django in my Web Programming class, and I'm having issues with the setup. My goal is to have a running default Django app, but, upon running `python manage.py runserver`, I get this syntax error for the default code:

```
File "manage.py", line 17
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried running it on python3, which produced a different error. See below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

I have Django installed via pip, and can use the `django-admin` command. My exact code can be created by running `django-admin startproject [name of project]`.

All the best,
Ben

Comment: Try using `python -m pip install django`, and run the server again?

Comment: That returns:
`bencarpenter@Dr-Bubbles lectureApp % python -m pip install django
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named pip`

Comment: Try using `python3 -m pip install django`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install Django using [built-in pip module](https://docs.python.org/2/installing/)

`python3 -m pip install django`